# How to use a filter condition on a windows functions in SQL

Tags: sql, scala, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Source:

```
AccNo   Amt     Date    
1       0       2/02/2021
1       200     2/02/2021
1       300     3/02/2021
2       400     1/03/2021
2       500     1/04/2021
```

Expected target:

```
AccNo   Amt     Date        no_of_times_non_0_past_week no_of_times_non_0_past_month    
1       0       2/02/2021   0                           0       
1       200     2/02/2021   0                           0       
1       300     3/02/2021   1                           1       
2       400     1/03/2021   0                           2       
2       500     1/04/2021   0                           1
```

Need to check the no of times amount was 0 in the past week and past month and so on.

I am currently using a windows functions to aggregate on the ranges(past week,past_month etc).
count(amt) over (partition by accNo order by Date   range between 7 preceding and current row)

Now checking if we can add a filter with amount as a non zero on this so I can count based on this filter.

Can we use a filter in addition to the windows function?
count(amt) over (partition by accNo order by Date   range between 7 preceding and current row)
where amt<> 0 ??

Comment: yes you can use that filter WHERE amt<> 0. What is the problem?

Comment: You can try something like this ```count(case when amt>0 then 1 end) over (partition by accNo order by Date rows between 7 preceding and current row)```

Comment: @AnotherDayAnotherData good to hear that .Adding this as an answer since the suggestion worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

`count(case when amt>0 then 1 end) over (partition by accNo order by Date rows between 7 preceding and current row)`

should do the trick for you.